# How To create a Dialog from clicking a button on a custom dialog?

Tags: java, android, onclick, dialog

For part of the app I am making. I have a button being selected in an options menu. When that button is clicked, It opens a custom dialog. I need buttons on that custom dialog to open a new Dialog, but for some reason my methodology causes the app to crash. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_app);

    //Copy and paste this line to onClick methods regarding the edit text dialog
   // textentry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entrybox);


  //  Button year = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Year);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
    return true;
}

//Dialog Box for selecting View books in Options Menu
public Dialog ViewBookOptions() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_books, null);
    builder.setView(v);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;



}

//Dialog boxes for selecting Year, Author, or Title in the ViewBook Dialog Box

public Dialog ViewByYear(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_entry, null);
    builder.setView(v);
    final EditText entrybox = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.entrybox);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String entry = entrybox.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                    //This is Where You Will Populate The ListView With Database Stuff
                }
            });
    builder.setNegativeButton(
            "Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(
                                DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;

}

             //Quick Toast for checking stuff
               public void toast(String string){
                 Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       //All of my button OnClick Methods
         public void allbooks(View view){
      toast("You clicked All books");
       }
           public void year(View view){
     toast("Dialog should open and EditText should change hint text");
     EditText textentry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entrybox);
      textentry.setHint("Enter the Year of the Book(s)");
      Dialog dialog = ViewByYear();
     dialog.show();
       }


        // The Options Menu
       @Override
       public boolean
         onOptionsItemSelected
         (MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.option1:
            //Change to View Book Options
            Dialog dialog = ViewBookOptions();
            dialog.show();
            return true;
        case R.id.option2:

            return true;
        case R.id.option3:

            return true;
        case R.id.option4:

            return true;
        case R.id.option5:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
       }
```

That is my activity code. I believe the error has something to do with the first dialog not being dismissed before the second dialog is created, but I am unsure how to correct this, because my dialogs are called by different buttons at different instances.

Comment: Can you post the fatal error log?

Comment: I recommend you to use `DialogFragment`, it can handle all the actions like rotation etc. for you. Check docs with examples here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: Looking this up now. Thanks so much!

Comment: Nevermind guys. It seems the issue was unrelated. I was also attempting to edit the hint in an edit text on creation of the second dialog. It appears that was throwing the error.

Comment: So my methodology was fine.
The textentry.setHint caused the error.
It would be much appreciated if anyone could tell me why.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try out **Sweet Alert Dialog Android Library**? It supports the use of nested dialogs in code. Here's the link: https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog